# How do you change default web path for Apache to a directory shared by Samba on Centos 7?

Tags: apache, samba, centos7

How do you change default web path for Apache to a directory shared by Samba on Centos 7?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount Samba Share in Apache Directory.
In Apache's httpd.conf under your VirtualHost section update DocumentRoot to the directory where you have mounted.